# Converting jQuery Isotope Filtering Code to Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm working on a project that utilizes Isotope Layout to filter HTML elements. Currently, I'm using jQuery to achieve the filtering functionality, but I'd like to transition to pure vanilla JavaScript for better performance and maintainability.

I've attempted to convert the jQuery code to vanilla JavaScript, but I'm encountering errors. Here's the original jQuery code that works as expected:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
    var $filter = $('#filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear'
        }
    });
    $filter.find('a').click(function() {
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $filter.find('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                animationDuration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false,
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

the code below is vanilla JavaScript but throw some errors including this one

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove') at HTMLAnchorElement.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var container = document.querySelector('.portfolioContainer');
    var filter = document.getElementById('filter');

    var iso = new Isotope(container, {
        itemSelector: '*',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear'
        }
    });
    filter = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    for (var linkElement of filter) {
        linkElement.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var selector = event.target.getAttribute("data-filter");
            selector.classList.remove("active");
            var iso = new Isotope(container, {
                itemSelector: '*',
                layoutMode: 'masonry',
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear'
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `selector` value is the value of whatever is in the "data-filter" attribute (so, a string). Strings do not have a `classList` of course. Probably you need to use `.querySelector()` to find the element that the "data-filter" property references.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few differences:

- `selector.classList.remove("active");` is not what the jQuery code is doing. The latter does not refer to `selector` here, but the collection of `a` elements below the filter.
- You don't have the equivalent of `$(this).addClass('active');`
- `filter = document.querySelectorAll('a');` is not the equivalent of `$filter.find('a')`. The latter only selects `a` elements *below* `$filter`, while your translation gets all of them, and overwrites `filter` -- ignoring what you had stored in `filter` before
- The second `itemSelector: '*'` does not correspond to the original `filter: selector`
- Not a problem, but you never use `iso`, so I'd suggest dropping the assignments to this variable.

Here is a correction (assuming the `Isotope` constructor is correct):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const container = document.querySelector('.portfolioContainer');
    const filter = document.getElementById('filter');

    new Isotope(container, {
        itemSelector: '*',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear'
        }
    });
    const links = filter.querySelectorAll('a');
    for (const linkElement of links) {
        linkElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
            for (const link of links) {
                link.classList.toggle("active", linkElement === link);
            }
            new Isotope(container, {
                itemSelector: this.getAttribute("data-filter"),
                layoutMode: 'masonry',
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear'
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```